# How to sync two MySQL tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table (lets call it `orders`) on one server of mine, named, for example, `local`. And I have this same table one another server of mine, named, for example, `remote`.

My problem is, what is the best way to sync these two tables?

I would like a solution that replaces a registry if the local is different of the remote one. And insert the registry if it doesn't exist on the local table.

I had tried using dump a dump command similar to this one, but didn't worked as expected:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --defaults-file=~/my/conf.cnf --skip-opt --skip-add-locks --default-character-set=latin1 --disable-keys --no-create-db --no-create-info --dump-date --compress --quick --replace --where='date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)' mydb orders >> /backup/myDump
```

How can I do this? How could I do a script to do this?

Comment: MySQL have a master/slave replication built in, is it overkill for your application? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Comment: Do you need bidirectional sync?  If so then you need some way to notate deletes, since an insert-only bidirectional sync will incorrectly recreate deleted rows.

Comment: @cdhowie, undirectional only.

Comment: No deletion, then? Else [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33677316/819417) works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

pt-table-sync can do this: http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-table-sync.html

See also [other SO questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pt-table-sync) mentioning pt-table-sync.

Comment: Do you know if I can install this tool on Mac too?

Comment: Yes, I use the Percona Toolkit on a Mac regularly.  You just need Perl and perhaps a few Perl modules.

Comment: I'm searching, but do you know how can I solve this warning? `Warning: prerequisite DBD::mysql 3 not found.` I had run `perl Makefile.PL`.

Comment: This command solved the warning to me: `sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Bundle::DBD::mysql'`.

Comment: This tool works fine. The optinos --print, --dry-run, --verbose are awesome. Thx a lot.

Comment: Looks mature. Has anyone tested it on production environment? Eg. syncing every one minute?

Comment: @recmund, pt-table-sync is not intended to be used continually. Replication is the solution for that.

Comment: @BillKarwin I'm specifically looking for sync over unreliable network (disconnects and so on...). As far as I've read, replication does not like these conditions and demands constant intervention of administrator.
I may be wrong.

Comment: @recmund, MySQL replication has an IO thread that will reconnect automatically if it loses a network connection.