# How to Sync two mysql manually for shared hosting

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have two database for my website one is online(Godaddy Shared Hosting) and one is offline(Xampp), I want to sync both database manually.

Because there is limited access of internet in the office so our data entry team put data on offline database,I want that data to sync everyday in evening after there shift to online godaddy database. what should be the easiest possible way of doing this, also noted that there are extra data generated everyday in online database by public.

PS: I am using Cakephp 2.4

Comment: Did you check this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577073/how-to-sync-two-mysql-tables

Comment: I am using Godaddy shared hosting so I don't have access in configuration files and I can't use MySQL replication

Comment: Ummm, so you want a whole manual replication? I mean, all the update, insert, deletes... sync between databases? And without any tool?

Comment: Yes but if there is any tool that can help me I would prefer that

Comment: You want replication, read the manual. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html I removed the CakePHP tag as well - this is cleary *not* related to anything php.

Comment: As I said earlier I can't use replication because I am using Shared Hosting, and I don't have access to configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

Just use classic file based replication with row based format.
Make offline database as read-only to avoid any unauthorized writes.