# How to sync a particular table with same name and database name between two different independent networks where replication is not possible?

Tags: mysql, synchronization

pt-table-sync and pt-table-checksum  still require the target and destination DBs to be in the same network. Is there an alternative, apart from import/export, replication, and pt-table-sync?

MySQL Version is 5.5 and above.

Answer (score 1):

As root:

```
mysqldump db table | mysql -h1.2.3.4 -uuser -password db
```

If permission is denied, this should work in the remote database:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'user'@'server1' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Automate using `crontab` or simply use a specialized tool like `pt-table-sync --execute h=host1,D=db,t=tbl h=host2`

If you can't reach part of your own network, check your [subnet masks](https://superuser.com/questions/656321/how-do-you-get-2-local-networks-to-talk-to-each-other).