# How to copy table from one table on remote server to table on a different remote database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I have matching databases on 2 different servers (mysql replication is not an option).
I need to see if a record is missing from one table2 and if so truncate table2 and then copy from table1 to table2.
each table is on a different IP/server.

code:

```
            $pdoyd = new PDO(
                    'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST_YODA . ';dbname=' . DB_DATABASE_DNS,
                     DB_USER_DNS,
                     DB_PASSWORD
            );
            $pdoyd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $pdoyd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            $truntbl = array('cryptokeys', 'domains', 'records');
            foreach($truntbl as $tbl){
                    $sql = 'truncate '.$tbl;
                    $statementyd = $pdoyd->prepare($sql);
                    $useryd = $statementyd->execute();
                    var_dump($statementyd);
                    echo '<br>';
            }
```

what is an efficient way to copy missing records from one table on 1 server to another table on a different server?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577073/how-to-sync-two-mysql-tables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can open two connections. Use one to read from the source server, the other two insert into the destination server. Use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE` option to prevent errors when you try to overwrite existing rows, so it only inserts the missing rows.

```
$pdo1 = new PDO('mysql:host=server1;dbname=xxx', $username1, $password1);
$pdo2 = new PDO('mysql:host=servrer2; dbname=xxx', $username2, $password2);

$insert_stmt = $pdo2->prepare("INSERT INTO yourTable (col1, col2, col3, ...) VALUES (:col1, :col2, :col3, ...) ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE");
$select_results = $pdo1->query("SELECT * FROM yourTable");
while ($row = $select_results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $insert_stmt->execute($row);
}
```

Comment: Change `fetchAll` to `fetch`. Or use `foreach ($select_results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row` instead of `while`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have to check for missing records and not for changed records, then you have 2 options:

1. Pull the primary keys from both tables into php arrays and use [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) function to get the list of pks that are present in one table and are not present in the other one. This method is efficient if there are not that many records in the tables.
2. Pull the primary keys from one table and insert them into a temporary table in the other database using bulk insert or load data infile sql commands. After that you can use left join with is null criterion in the where clause to get list of pks that are not available in the other table.

On the longer run you may try to establish which records have been fully synced using auto increment field or timestamp to track progress. You need to check subsequent records only.

Comment: actually the keys don't matter. how to copy it from one table to another, when on different servers is still the primary issue.  Should be just an simple one line SQL query like "copy ipaddress.database.table1 to differentipaddress.database.table1  ...  The keys can be in any order. Original would be nice, but no biggie if not.

Comment: You cannot do this, the 2 servers are not connected directly. You will have to transfer the data via php.

Comment: Obviously, you can export the full table from one system into a file and import it into the other server and php is only used for transferring the file.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your PHPAdmin and try to export the table. Then open the .sql file in your text editor and find the missing data. Lastly, remove any duplicate data and try using the MySQL code from the .sql file and put it into the terminal with the destination.

Comment: Howdo you suggest to do this with pdo?

Comment: @Angus Leung  I'm in the middle of PDO brother. I want nothing to do with a GUI. I'm going to let joe schmuckatelli from Timbuktu access my backend datebase?  o.0  This is a function is in a custom app.  But thank you though.

Comment: awesome! Hope you succeed!